# How can I authenticate a user in LDAP within multiple OU with variable levels in APEX?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, oracle-apex

I'm having a few problems trying to implement a LDAP authentication scheme in Oracle APEX. As an example I will post my DN here

> `CN=MyUsername,OU=Users,OU=MyDepartment,OU=MyManagementUnit,OU=MyDirectiveUnit,OU=MyLocation,OU=MyCompany,DC=example,DC=com`

.

From this data, the only constants for what I want to accomplish are `CN=MyUsername,OU=Users ... OU=MyLocation,OU=MyCompany,DC=example,DC=com`, while these `OU=MyDepartment, OU=MyManagementUnit, OU=MyDirectiveUnit` can change from user to user.

In the Apex Authentication Scheme I have the following values:

- **LDAP Host**: `example.com`
- **Port**: `default`
- **Use SSL**: `No`
- **Use Exact Distinguished Name (DN)**: `No`
- **DN String**: `OU=MyLocation,OU=MyCompany,DC=example,DC=com`
- **Search filter**: `(cn=%LDAP_USER%)(&(objectClass=user)(|(OU=*)(OU=*)))` and `(cn=%LDAP_USER%)(&(objectClass=user)(OU=*,OU=*,OU=*)` have been my most recent tries.

After everything, I keep getting this error message:

> Authentication failed ORA-31202: DBMS_LDAP: LDAP client/server error:
>   Operations error. 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order
>   to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the
>   connection., data 0, v1db1

I've read a bit these past few days about Active Directory but I am unable to understand it fully (at least with big multi-level, multi-groups trees). Any tips and/or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You need to be logged in to perform the search. Normally you would provide a lot hin for application with suitable privileges for this purpose, with a fixed DN. NB It's probably already too late, but it is a *big* mistake to have your DIT mapped directly onto your organizational structure.

Comment: Ok, a couple of questions: what is the DIT? and, why is it such a mistake? thank you for your input!
Edit: now I know what the DIT is, but not why it is a mistake.

Comment: DIT => Directory Information Tree. It is a mistake because users change departments, become/cease to be managers, resign/retire/get rehired as something else, ..., and because divisions appear, merge, and disappear, and you don't want *any* of that activity to require wholesale changes to the DIT. You want to manage what groups and managers and roles a user has via attributes, not via position in the DIT. The DIT should consist of broad and unchangeable subtrees like Users, Roles, Departments, ..., with cross-references between them handled via attributes and aliases, Not via structure.